# Monitor if any new blob appeared in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage

I am using Spring Boot with `com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage-spring-boot-starter`dependency to connect to Azure Blob Storage.

I have created a blob container to get access to a particular container:

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public CloudBlobContainer blobContainer(CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount) {
    return cloudStorageAccount
            .createCloudBlobClient()
            .getContainerReference(containerName);
}
```

The goal of mine is to monitor if someone uploads a new blob to download it and process.

Comment: You should look into using Event Grid: It will emit an event when a new blob gets created and you can consume that event in your Java app and process further: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal

Answer (score 1):

Just as silent mentioned, you can use [Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal). It is the official suggested approach.

But, there are always some other ways.

For example, you can use Azure function app, and use storage blob trigger. In this way, each time a new blob is uploaded, the function will be triggered. Here is a quickstart tutorial: [Create a function triggered by Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function)

Another choice is to use Azure logic app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage

Hope it helps.